# Two-phase commit: availability, scalability and performance issues

Tags: database, scalability, distributed-transactions, 2phase-commit, consensus

I have read a number of articles and got confused.

Opinion 1:
2PC is very efficient, a minimal number of messages are exchanged and latency is low.
Source:
http://highscalability.com/paper-consensus-protocols-two-phase-commit

Opinion 2:
It is very hard to scale distributed transactions to high level, moreover they reduce throughput. As 2PC guarantess ACID It puts a great burden due to its complex coordination algorithm.
Source: http://ivoroshilin.com/2014/03/18/distributed-transactions-and-scalability-issues-in-large-scale-distributed-systems/

Opinion 3:
“some authors have claimed that two-phase commit is too expensive to support, because 
of the performance or availability problems that it brings. We believe it is better to have 
application programmers deal with performance problems due to overuse of transactions 
as bottlenecks arise, rather than always coding around the lack of transactions. Running 
two-phase commit over Paxos mitigates the availability problems.”
Source: http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep552/13sp/lectures/6/spanner.pdf

Opinion 4:
The 2PC coordinator also represents a Single Point of Failure, which is unacceptable for critical systems - I believe it is a coordinator.
Source: http://www.addsimplicity.com/adding_simplicity_an_engi/2006/12/2pc_or_not_2pc_.html

First 3 opinions contradict each other. The 4-th one I think is correct. Please clarify what is wrong and what is correct. It would be great also to give facts why that is.

Comment: _"2PC guarantees ACID"_: no it cannot. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639740

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 4th statement is correct, but maybe not in the way you are reading it. In 2PC, if the coordinator fails, the system cannot make progress. It therefore often desirable to use a fault-tolerant protocol like Paxos (see [Gray and Lamport](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1132863.1132867) for example), which will allow the system to safely progress when there are failures.

Opinion 3 should be read in context of the rest of the Spanner paper. The authors are saying that they have developed a system which allows efficient transactions in a distributed database, and that they think it's the right default tradeoff for users of the system. The way Spanner does that is well detailed in the paper, and it is worth reading. Take note that Spanner is simply a way (a clever way, granted) of organizing the coordination which is inherently required to implement serializable transactions. See [Gilbert and Lynch](http://lpd.epfl.ch/sgilbert/pubs/BrewersConjecture-SigAct.pdf) for one way to look at the limits on coordination).

Opinion 2 is a common belief, and there are indeed tradeoffs between availability and richness of transaction semantics in real-world distributed systems. Current research, however, is making it clear that these tradeoffs are not as dire as they have been portrayed in the past. See [this talk by Peter Bailis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rAdJkAbGls) for one of the research directions. If you want true serializability or linearizability in the strictest sense, you need to obey certain lower bounds of coordination in order to achieve them.

Opinion 1 is technically true, but not very helpful in the way you quoted it. 2PC is optimal in some sense, but seldom implemented naively because of the availability tradeoffs. Many adhoc attempts to adress these tradeoffs lead to incorrect protocols. Others, like Paxos and Raft, successfully address them at the cost of some complexity.